# Problem in installation in my system which preilstalled XP

Tags: system-installation

So I downloaded and burned to a dvd placed the dvd in my computer restarted the computer and nothing happens. I dont get it would you guys please give me a hand here?

I have a Window XP Emachine.

Comment: Have you checked your boot order in your BIOS (press an F key during boot up to enter... there'll be a message on screen telling you how)  It's not impossible the ordered excludes booting from optical media

Comment: I've tried changing all kinds of order and nothing is working.

Comment: When you burned the DvD did you burn the .iso file as Data or as a Image? You have to burn it as a Image for it to work.

Comment: I burned it at .iso How do I burn it as an image?

Comment: http://instagram.com/p/hrGi0Jra2O/

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Answer (score 0):

Verify the MD5SUM of ISO file. Look this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto

Or you can try booting from USB. ;) (If your BIOS have support!)

Comment: I'm 100% noob status!   ?????.....

Comment: I found out know what what I do to try and change the order my computer will always read the HD first. So I need to manually install how do I do that?

Comment: JimmyeMassey, I can't say that you are noob... Just, you need consider one error in this media, file missing or something. Sorry, If I can try help u... :(

Comment: In some computer BIOS, press F12 for change your boot sequence or access your BIOS Setup (DEL or F2 or F10) and looking for the BOOT Sequence.

Comment: Jimmy, I saw your video at Instagram! I've had such problems ... Many times it is error in the reader. :( I have one portable reader for these cases...

Comment: You might be on to something there about the reader.

Comment: I downloaded Wubi to install Ubuntu but when I open the Wubi application and go throw the steps at the very end. It say I need something like 456mb and I only have 446 avalible. I went into the remove area of the computer to get rid of silly stuff and try to install but it still says the same thing. So I went ahead and install anyways and needless to say it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I learn that you are a noob and that is why for a clear understanding for beginners I have posted complete installation of ubuntu 12.04 on my blog. Like you, I too faced this hurdle and so I thought of helping the people :)
Check it out.-->

http://crazzycmd.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/ubuntu-installation/

I'm sure this would solve ur query completely.